# Joomla 3.x - Weird signs and symbols

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

Recently moved upgraded site to different directory and updated database tables with live site tables. The site was displaying correctly on test environment, but after migration some weird characters started showing on admin section. Please check screenshot. Anyone have any solutions to this?! tried switching to Hathor and it's also missing icons. Looked at media > jui and even re-uploaded the files, but nothing.

[image]

Comment: You don't say what you migrated from, but make sure you have the full jui files and the full files for Isis and system.  Basically you're missing the icons.

Comment: I  checked. Everything seems to be intact in the ISIS folder. It's not only ISIS; I tried with Hathor and it's also missing icons. The site I had it in a test environment, I just moved it to live directory. As for database changes, I updated user tables.

Comment: Check your media folder against what is in a standard package, it really looks like you are missing the icons.  What version did you update from?

Comment: Everything in a standard package is in the media folder. No updates done on Joomla. Also tried reuploading the files to see if anything was missing, but no luck.

Comment: "Recently moved upgraded site"  I'm sorry but this makes it sound like it was upgraded but now you are saying it was a totally fresh install?

Comment: Try checking the lines `6182-6188` in `administrator/templates/isis/css/templates.css` where the `src:` paths for the `@font-face` are declared and play around to see if something has moved from where it should have been.

Comment: @Elin the icons were working fine on test environment, and by "upgraded site", I meant new changes to previous design with no changes on Joomla files. The issue started once the files were moved to root directory.

Comment: @ilias yea, I looked through that CSS file and played with the paths, but still no luck. Already checked media > jui folder and everything seems to be fine. Neither ISIS or HATHOR are showing the icons in admin area.

Comment: Try recompiling the LESS.

Comment: @Elin Haven't worked with LESS. Do you have a good step by step on how to do this? And which file do I recompile? Since I don't think it's an ISIS issue. Because Hathor is also missing the icons.

Comment: Try going to the template manager, templates view for isis and then open the template.less file. Then click the recompile button and see if it helps.  ALso, try going to the demo site and compare what you see on inspect elements there with what you get on inspect elements on your site.

Comment: What is your web browser and its version @Kakenx ?

Comment: @Elin No luck on compile.

Comment: @HungTran Using FF26 and Chrome 32.0.1700.72 m.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was caused by htaccess. Was rewriting webfonts to lowercase thus causing this issue.

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same problems as shown in the image above. Turned out, I had unchecked "Allow pages to use their own fonts" in the browser's font setup.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. The htaccess file was not the htaccess suggested by Joomla so I changed it to the one that comes with Joomla and that fixed the problem.

Comment: Would be good to include the .htaccess file in question, to make it easier for other people looking for the answer.